# How to have laravel pagination links using the bootstrap 4 default pagination styles?

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel default pagination with:
                                                `{{$posts->links()}}` and the pagination works, the links appear and it works correct.

But the style is like this:

[image]

Do you know why is not using the bootstrap 4 default styles? I'm using Bootstrap 4.

Also I have inside views/vendor/pagination the files:

```
- bootstrap4-blade.php
-default.blade.php
-semantic-ui.blade.php
-simple-bootstra-4.blade.php
-simple-default.blade.php
```

Generated HTML:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li>
    <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://proj.test/user/profile?page=2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://proj.test/user/profile?page=2" rel="next">»</a></li>
</ul>
```

In "http://proj.test/css/app.css" it appears:

```
.pagination {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.page-item:first-child .page-link {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.page-item:last-child .page-link {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.page-item.active .page-link {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0FACF3;
  border-color: #0FACF3;
}

.page-item.disabled .page-link {
  color: #868e96;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.page-link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  margin-left: -1px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  color: #0FACF3;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.page-link:focus,
.page-link:hover {
  color: #097aad;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  border-color: #ddd;
}

.pagination-lg .page-link {
  padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.pagination-lg .page-item:first-child .page-link {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.pagination-lg .page-item:last-child .page-link {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.pagination-sm .page-link {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.pagination-sm .page-item:first-child .page-link {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.2rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.2rem;
}

.pagination-sm .page-item:last-child .page-link {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.2rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2rem;
}
```

In the page is loaded:

```
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://proj.test/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://proj.test/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://proj.test/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Is bootstrap linked in your page? Could you please post the generated html code?

Comment: Yes Im using other bootstrap 4 components, I update the question with that.

Comment: are you sure the bootstrap.min.css is loaded with the page and there is no error in console? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: Thanks, the css is loaded in the page, in the console appear an error but related to datepicker "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

Comment: But Im using bootstrap sass in the app.scss file I have "@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";" to import the bootstrap components.

Comment: I remove the datepicker error but the pagination still appears with same style.

Comment: Is your sass with bootstrap 'compiled'? For example with 'npm run dev'?
Is your cahce cleared?

Comment: Yes, in the console it appears that the asset /js/app.js and /css/app.css is compiled. With "php artisan cache:clear" the pagination layout still appears the same.

Comment: Please have a look in the vendor pagination view:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Comment: Because somthing is wrong with your html. It should look like this:
`<ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item disabled">
                <span class="page-link">‹</span>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item active">
                <span class="page-link">1</span>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="/?page=2">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="/?page=2" rel="next">›</a>
        </li>
</ul>`

Comment: Thanks, it seems that it works with "{{$posts->links(("pagination::bootstrap-4"))}}".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customize the view used to display pagination passing it as a parameter of the `links` method:

```
{{ $paginator->links('your.view') }}
```

You can even customize the default view applied using `Paginator::defaultView` in your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    Paginator::defaultView('pagination::view');
}
```

Check out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view) for further information.

Answer (score 2):

Because the view is not yet available, we need to publish the view. Please run the following command in the terminal / CMD:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

Answer (score 2):

If laravel pagination is not using bootstrap paginations style, then try the following code in AppServiceProvider.php file to make bootstrap pagination.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
     Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```